# Why does my service not start on BOOT_COMPLETED?

Tags: android

In order to create a service which starts whenever the device starts, I have taken the suggestions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934949/loading-a-service-after-booting-in-android) and [here](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-start-an-application-at-device-bootup-in-android). The build finishes fine, and the main activity also starts fine on a Nexus-5 virtual device.

However, when I check the logcat output to verify the service is started, there is no mentioning of the text `MYLOG` I write to logcat in the `BackgroundService` class. This leads me to believe, that the code below is not working properly. Also, I do not see the `Toast` when booting up the virtual device. What am I missing?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alexander.bootservice">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.alexander.bootservice.BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.example.alexander.bootservice.BackgroundService"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Broadcast receiver class**

```
package com.example.alexander.bootservice;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Created by alexander on 13/06/16.
 */

public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**service class**

```
package com.example.alexander.bootservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by alexander on 13/06/16.
 */
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d("MYLOG", "onCreate has been called");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service` classes don't appear to be in the correct package. With that `<receiver>` `name`, it's looking for `com.example.alexander.bootservice.BootCompletedIntentReceiver`.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you are saying. Because I think I have a file at location `com.example.alexander.bootservice.BootCompletedIntentReceiver`. It's called `BootCompletedIntentReceiver.java` and contains a class named `BootCompletedIntentReceiver`. I am confused! What do you suggest to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm a little confused, too, then, 'cause I'd think your IDE would be throwing a fit if you have the wrong `package` specified in a class. Anyhoo, make sure both classes are in the right place, and that they both have `package com.example.alexander.bootservice;` at the top.

Comment: Each package has `package com.example.alexander.bootservice;` at the top, and the manifest contains `receiver android:name="com.example.alexander.bootservice.BootCompletedIntentReceiver"` and `service android:name="com.example.alexander.bootservice.BackgroundService"`. But still no sign of the `Toast` or the expected log-entry...

Comment: Dunno. All I could recommend is to double-check everything - make sure those correct classes actually have the code you've posted, delete the classes with `package com.example.newtest;`, clean/rebuild, retry. And, as CommonsWare pointed out, make sure to launch your `Activity` at least once after installation before testing the reboot.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just copied the code from the other post. I have updated the three code pieces to the ones I actually am using. And yes. I install the changed code all the  time first, then I reboot the virtual device.

Comment: Ah, OK. Then the only other thing I can add is that it may take a while for your Receiver to fire. It's not necessarily going to happen as soon as the home screen appears, so you might need to give it a minute or two.

Comment: I just checked - I finally found the MYLOG entry!! Damn, II need to become more patient...!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"` from your `<receiver>`. That says that whoever *sends* the broadcast has to hold the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission, and that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Does not seem to work. I do not find the text "MYLOG" in my logcat output (no filters, Level on Debug).

Comment: @Alex: See also Mike's comment on your question. You seem to have some package name discrepancies. Also, make sure that you have run the activity at least once on the device before attempting the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working absolutely fine. The reason why you are not seeing the "MYLOG" in logcat is because you are expecting it to see it the first time you are installing the app on the emulator.

You need to install the app on the device and open it once before you can receive intent with action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` on every boot completion. If you install the app and not open it(possible with adb install on real phone), on reboot your app will not get intent action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

To test, install the app on the emulator and open it. Then use `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` command in your terminal to send this action. Your device will restart and you will be able to see the log and your toast. Let me know if there is any confusion.

And yes you should remove android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" from receiver as suggested in one of the answers, its not needed.